# sencha touch 2 app not displaying in android browser completely

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a completely working Sencha Touch2 example app running on my python single threaded server (django like runserver) on my laptop. It uses jsonp to load images for carousel similar to example here http://edspencer.net/2012/02/building-a-data-driven-image-carousel-with-sencha-touch-2.html

It works on my Chrome and partially on firefox.

I followed the guide to make the production build from docs in Sencha Touch 2. All good here too on Chrome. Here are the requests I see.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:21:15] "GET /static/build/production/cache.manifest HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:21:16] "GET /static/build/production/app.json?1341246076009 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:21:16] "GET /static/build/production/src/log/Logger.js?_dc=1341246076006 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:21:16] "GET /static/build/production/deltas/app.js/812d759b7c7a366ab0976c13044b2cd38f3444dc.json?1341246076040 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:21:16] "GET /static/build/production/src/log/Base.js?_dc=1341246076130 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:21:16] "GET /static/build/production/src/log/writer/Console.js?_dc=1341246076307 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:21:16] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:21:16] "GET /static/build/production/src/log/writer/Writer.js?_dc=1341246076347 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:21:16] "GET /static/build/production/src/log/formatter/Formatter.js?_dc=1341246076386 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:21:16] "GET /static/build/production/src/log/formatter/Default.js?_dc=1341246076449 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:21:16] "GET /w00t/?_dc=1341246076539&page=1&start=0&limit=25&callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Now I head over to my android Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (android 3.x) on wifi to access the sencha app via the LAN IP (I tried android phones too)

Here I see my loading indicator and then blam... black blank screen.
I see the requests are incomplete. here are the requests:

```
192.168.0.109 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:24:24] "GET /static/build/production/index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.109 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:24:24] "GET /static/build/production/cache.manifest HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.109 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:24:24] "GET /static/build/production/app.json?1341246263383 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.109 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:24:24] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
192.168.0.109 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:24:24] "GET /static/build/production/resources/css/app.css?1341246263429 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.109 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:24:24] "GET /static/build/production/sdk/sencha-touch.js?1341246263432 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.109 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:24:25] "GET /static/build/production/app.js?1341246263436 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.109 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:24:26] "GET /static/build/production/src/log/Logger.js?_dc=1341246265378 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.109 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:24:26] "GET /static/build/production/app.json?1341246265382 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.109 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:24:27] "GET /static/build/production/src/log/Base.js?_dc=1341246265428 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.109 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:24:27] "GET /static/build/production/src/log/writer/Console.js?_dc=1341246265780 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.109 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:24:27] "GET /static/build/production/src/log/writer/Writer.js?_dc=1341246265830 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.109 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:24:27] "GET /static/build/production/src/log/formatter/Formatter.js?_dc=1341246265870 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.0.109 - - [03/Jul/2012 00:24:27] "GET /static/build/production/src/log/formatter/Default.js?_dc=1341246265912 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

It always gets stuck at Default.js

I am no JS ninja and evaluating Sencha touch 2 for a touch friendly version of my site.
It's sad I cannot try my nifty touch swipe carousel :( I have to mouse swipe on my chrome and be content of my lame achievements. Getting this to work has been my goal for past night and I would love to see it work.

P.S. The actual example does work on tab beautifully. But it could have been made in a different (older) version of ST2. I am using 2.0.2 here. I copy pasted most of the code from the example and changed a few minor things to fit my aesthetic desires.

TIA